# Problems with Jquery UI resizable/draggable div in canvas

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DdZMRq19cyzvczLigxG4?p=preview) I'm appending divs to a canvas. The divs are resizable and draggable (using Jquery UI).

The objective is to resize/drag many divs within the limits of a canvas.

New divs are created by clicking the button. These should be created at top=50px, left=50px with respect to the canvas.

There are several problems:

1 - if you click on "New Div" many times, the top/left attributes are not respected even though I'm forcing them (new divs are created further down).

2 - if you resize the divs, at one point for some reason the canvas height is reduced to 0px

3 - if I move the divs around the canvas, I expect the canvas to enlarge to contain the divs, as divs are appended to the canvas. Still, you see that the canvas border not always contains the divs.

What's wrong with this code?

HTML

```
<button onclick="add()">New Div</button>
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

CSS

```
.div1 { width: 160px; height: 200px; position:absolute; border:1px solid black; background-color: #d2d2d2 }
canvas {width: 100%; height: 100%;border:1px dashed gray; position:relative;}
```

Javascript

```
function add(){

    var $canvas = $("#canvas");
    var $div = $("<div></div>");
    $div.appendTo($canvas);

    // this is what doesn't work
    $div.css({ top: '50px', left: '50px' });

    $div.draggable();   
    $div.resizable();
    $div.addClass('div1');

}
```